# Using different samba client configurations

Tags: printing, samba, file-sharing

One of the file shares on a samba server I'm using requires that I add the `client use spnego = no` in the `[global]` section of `/etc/samba/smb.conf`. However, when the config file has that configuration, I cannot use the samba printers from another server.

The current solution I'm using is having a different `smb.conf` files when I want to print. Obviously, this is very inconvenient.

Is there a way to conditionally configure the samba client based on the resource it is accessing?